# How to send data payload to all the users using Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send some message using Firebase Cloud Messaging service to all my users who are using the app. I can send data payload to a single or multiple devices using `regisration_ids` like this :

```
{

    "data": {
      "body":"body",
        "my_custom_key" : "215",
        "other_key" : true
     },
           "registration_ids": ["dCmhVkVMmLw:APA91bE5.."]

}
```

But how do I send data payload to all the users?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase Cloud Messaging - Send message to all users](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39772167/firebase-cloud-messaging-send-message-to-all-users)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `topics`, you need to subscribe all users/devises to a topic and then perform send request.

You can read more about it here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging