# Send notification globally using FCM

Tags: php, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send notification to my iOS application from server side. I am using PHP at server side and FCM to send notifications. I have the server_key for my firebase project.

I sent the following to FCM

```
{
  "to": "red_id",
  "data": {
    "message": "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!",
   }
}
```

But I want to send notification globally without using "to" clause. Need help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase Cloud Messaging - Send message to all users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39772167/firebase-cloud-messaging-send-message-to-all-users)

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Cloud Messaging always send messages to specific targets. While those targets can be broad, there is no way to send untargeted messages.

If you want to send a message to all users of your app, the easiest way is to [have your app subscribe to a topic](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/send-multiple#subscribe_the_client_app_to_a_topic) (e.g. `all` on startup. That way you can target all users of your app, by [sending a message to topic](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send_messages_to_topics) `/topic/all`.