# is it impossible to broadcast message with fcm push server in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I'm dev-ing nodejs server for push server. so I downloaded private key and set up this file.
but I faced with some problems. as I see many examples, there is a token. I realized that token is for sending to specific device. but I wanna send all devices.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = require('./firebase_account/firebase_account.json');

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "url"
  });


const registrationToken =""
const payload={
    notification:{
        title:"title",
        body:"body"
    }
}

admin.messaging().sendToDevice(registrationToken,payload,"")
    .then(function(response){
        console.log(response)
    })
    .catch(function(error){
        console.log(response)
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way built in API to send a message to all devices. The most common approach to implement this is to subscribe all clients to a specific topic (e.g. `/topics/all`), and then send a message to that topic.

- [Java Firebase cloud message . Send message to all](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43412489)
- [JSON Data to send Push Notification to all of the registered devices using Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39690293/json-data-to-send-push-notification-to-all-of-the-registered-devices-using-fireb/39697346#39697346)
- [How do you send a Firebase Notification to all devices via CURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38237559/how-do-you-send-a-firebase-notification-to-all-devices-via-curl/38248296#38248296)