# How does Firebase handles sending of multicast messages

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

As per firebase docs

> registration_ids:
>    This parameter specifies a list of devices (registration tokens, or IDs) receiving a multicast message. It must contain at least 1 and at most 1000 registration tokens.

I would like to know how if the devices are up to 1 million. How does Firebase handles sending of messages to all the devices without any delay to any device having sending 1000 devices at once.

Comment: The suggested way is to use topics.

Comment: Yes. Suppose if I like to send a marketing notification, how do I use the topic because the marketing notification is general where I like to market a new product and notify all users. Here the topic messaging won't come into picture right as marketing notification is not confined to a specific topic where specific users are subscribed, I want to multicast to all the users. And one more thing how does fcm manage sending more than 1000 users subscribed to a topic

Comment: There is no limit on the number of users that can be subscribed to a topic. If you want to have the ability to deliver a message to all users of your app, you'll typically want to subscribe all users to a topic (e.g. `/topics/all`) when the app starts. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/38237559, and https://stackoverflow.com/a/37636149

Comment: Yes I know that there is no limit for topic subscription but I like to know earlier FCM( it was GCM) can send 1000 messages at once and that we have to do in batches. I would like to know how did FCM overcome this batch processing and can able to send push notifications to millions of users subscribed to a topic instantaneously. Does it internally do a batch processing.